# Is TransmogrifAI compatible for MLFlow through MLeap

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, transmogrifai

I have created a model using TransmogrifAI. I am trying to load that model into MLFlow using MLeap, and unable to do so.

I basically used the bundle feature in MLeap, but no use. Anyone has any ideas to go forward?

Answer (score 1):

We are planning to add MLeap model export in the near future. For now you can use our transmogrifai-local library to serve models without Spark - https://github.com/salesforce/TransmogrifAI/tree/master/local

Comment: Does this add the MLeap support? https://github.com/salesforce/TransmogrifAI/pull/327

Comment: No. TransmogrifAI still uses custom serialization format for saving models. MLeap is currently used for serving models without Spark - https://github.com/salesforce/TransmogrifAI/tree/master/local

Comment: is MLeap in the roadmap of TransmogrifAI for model serving? How do you currently serve models (pipelines) built with transmogrifai?

Comment: There are two possible ways to serve models: (1) using Spark - http://docs.transmogrif.ai/en/stable/developer-guide/index.html#loading-saved-workflows  or (2) using local library (https://github.com/salesforce/TransmogrifAI/tree/master/local#transmogrifai-local). We are planning to Implement a model export runnable on MLeap alone is on our roadmap - https://github.com/salesforce/TransmogrifAI/pull/394